# Cross-browser padding/margins

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I was wondering if you could give me some helpful hints on how to correct this issue? I have a main menu on my site, the code for it is as follows:

```
li:hover {
    background-color: #222222;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}
```

And here's a demo of what it actually looks like:

[image: menu li overflow in browsers other than IE]

The problem is that when I hover over a menu option (li), the background appears, but it overflows to the outside of the menu's background, and makes it look really dodgy/crap/cheap/yuck!

Note that (obviously) when I change the padding to make it display correctly in these browsers, it appears too small in height in IE! So I'm screwed either way. How can I make little imperfections like this look the same in all browsers?

## Update:

HTML (The menu):

```
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="currentPage" href="index.php"><a>Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="support.php">Support</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="myaccount/" class="myaccount">My Account</a></li>
            </ul>
```

The CSS:

```
.menu {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    width: 345px;
    float: right;
}

li {
    font-size: 9pt;
    color: whitesmoke;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}

li:hover {
    background-color: #222222;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your HTML and more of your CSS? A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example would help lots.

Comment: @usoban, nope! If I use CSS Reset now, will I have to change the rest of my padding/margins/positioning throughout the site?

Comment: @thirtydot, sure! I will update my question.

Comment: @Lucifer: A CSS Reset just gets rid of the browser-specific defaults on attributes like `margin` and `padding`.. Using it normally makes it *easier* to get your page looking the same in all browsers.

Comment: Well, it depends, but probably you'd have to correct quite a few things. Basically, CSS reset will set all paddings&margins by default to 0, which forces you to set padding and margin for each element specifically. That results in (probably) the best cross-browser compatibility. If browser doesn't display it right, it's a matter of css hack.

Comment: @jnpcl, @usoban, @thirtydot thanks! :) I'll go get a reset and see what happens.

Comment: @Lucifer: I haven't looked yet since your update, but if a reset does fix it, all you really need is one or two properties adding to the CSS you gave us.

Comment: EEEEEEeeeeeeeewwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww grose! You should see what happened lol. Everything went ugly! But, I readjusted one page and now it is displaying perfectly in all the browsers I have tested it on. Thanks all! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might prevent problems by not changing the padding based on the hover. Furthermore you should hover on the a

Does this work as expected?
[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/VKTDv/)

Comment: I was just about to post the exact same thing.  An element's size should **not** be changed on hover; that's a recipe for disaster.  Also, the `a` should be the element with the padding and the `:hover` definition so that the entire box is clickable.  [Here's the JSFiddle I was working up to demonstrate these fixes.](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/8wTda/) **Edit:** ...and then you edited to include a JSFiddle of your own.  Way to be constantly one step ahead of me.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems are probably due to your use of display: inline. Try setting explicit height on the ul. Doing this with your example worked for me:

```
ul {
 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
 height: 28px;
}
```

I added the border to be able to see where I was aligning to.

BTW, the proper solution is to not use li:hover, but a:hover, as has been stated.